# Can I Install Termux on Linux?

Tags: linux, android, termux

We can install a Linux sub-system like CentOS or Ubuntu on Termux, but is it possible to have a Termux-like sub-system on Linux?

In Termux the installations of some packages are much easier with *pkg install*. And Termux provides many resources that cannot be obtained directly using one line of code  on pure Linux.

I came up with this idea when I was learning Termux on my phone and found the limited screen and soft keyboard really troublesome.

(don't tell me that I need an Android emulator or virtual machine)

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please expand your post to explain _why_ you want to have a termux-like system on Linux. Do you want to run android softare on a Linux system?

Comment: what exactly are you missing on your desktop that you have on Termux?   I use mostly debian on desktop and sometimes Termux on my phone and tablet - and tend to think of termux as a cut-down subset of what my debian machines can do.  Maybe the problem is just that your not as familiar with desktop linux as you are with termux, and if you tell us what you need to do, we can tell you how to do it on centos or ubuntu.

Comment: Well, I am just getting started so I am not familiar with both. I do have some problems with desktop Linux, and I am trying to find solutions in this community. Here I ask this question mostly for curiosity.

Comment: How is `pkg install` much easier than `apt install` ?

Answer (score 0):

Termux is not like a full distribution, it's more like a chroot environment.
Termux is not using basics Linux command, it use a portage of Linux commands on android, so that means you cannot just install it on your Linux distribution. But after some research i found that [termux docker container](http://docker%20run%20-it%20xeffyr/termux:x86_64). I don't think it's the exact same termux than on android but i think that can be a good start to develop scripts for your android device.

Either, i think you should go for an android VM on your linux machine to get the exact same environment and all the comfort of a big screen, a mouse and a keyboard